# Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'

Tags: angular, rxjs

For the sake of preventing downvotes, I will lorem-ipsum-elaborate on this error message:

I am using angular4 and out of the blue (well actually it's rather grey today) this error occured. Can anybody help? I already found similar issues on github, but no answers as to resolve the situation (I have tried "npm update" and "npm install")

Typescript version is 2.4.0

Additional error-messages are:

> Class 'WebSocketSubject' incorrectly extends base class 'AnonymousSubject'
>
> Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.

The location of the original error mnessage is given as 
"./node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts"

Comment: This problem may be related to this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2539

Comment: This has been fixed in rxjs@5.4.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think I solved it by the help of Haseoh's comment:

in the compiler-options for typescript (tsconfig.json) set

```
    "skipLibCheck": true
```

this is obviously a hack, but it solves my issue and I have grown accustomed to this kind of life since I started using angular2

Comment: Yup, this is legit hack. It seems we have to wait for official fix :)

Comment: I believe the preferred work-around is `noStrictGenericChecks`.

Comment: ("skipLibCheck": true  )                     It's really working, Thanks